# Using the Python kubernetes API, is there a way to list secrets in "my current namespace"?

Tags: python, kubernetes

The Python `kubernetes` module provides two methods for listing secrets:

- `list_namespaced_secret`
- `list_secret_for_all_namespaces`

I want to list the secrets for the namespace in which a container is running.

The `list_secret_all_for_namespaces` method isn't appropriate because it attempts to list secrets at the cluster scope, and I don't need or want that level of access.

The `list_namespaced_secret` method requires an explicit namespace name. I can provide that as an argument to my Python code...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: my-sandbox
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - /path/to/my-python-code.py
    arguments:
    - my-sandbox
```

...but that's clumsy, because it means the pod manifest needs to be
modified every time it's deployed to a new namespace.

Is there a way to acquire the current namespace name via the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the answers pointing at the [dowward api](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/), but I was hoping for something that would be independent from the pod manifest.

It looks like the namespace is exposed via the `ServiceAccount` information injected into the container, in `/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace`. This is available whether or not your pod has an explicit `ServiceAccountName`.

Answer (score 5):

If you could use `fieldRef` in the pod's manifest to set the env variable.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-envars-fieldref
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv
          sleep 10;
        done;
      env:
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE # <----this
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
  restartPolicy: Never
```

You can read the env variable and consume it with `list_namespaced_secret`.

```
from kubernetes import client, config
import os

config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

k = v1.list_namespaced_secret(str(os.environ.get("MY_POD_NAMESPACE")))
for i in k.items:
    print(i.metadata.name)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set an environment variable in this manifest that will be auto-populated when your Pod is deployed. See this stackoverflow answer for how to do that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57809472/16894714

Then you can simply access the environment variable from within your python script and call `list_namespaced_secret`.